# Cannot add Google Passes to wallet that I have generated

Tags: jwt, google-pay, google-wallet

I am working on allowing users of my mobile app to add passes to their wallets on their mobile devices. I have had success with iOS, and thought I just had a breakthrough with Google, but have now ran into an issue.

I followed Google's documentation on generating Generic Passes, and adding them to the wallet. I have a class `<ISSUER_ID>.traderLicenceClass`, and added this to the `classId` attribute of my new object, and then I followed the same structure I saw used for the object's ID, being `<ISSUER_ID>.traderLicenceClass<ID>`.

I sent my request via PostMan to my server, and got the token back from my `JWT` claims request. I was then able to click this link on web and mobile, and add the pass to my wallet.

However, when I then tried generating a new pass, using the same object, but just changing the ID, I get the token from `JWT`, but when I try to add it to my wallet, it just says `Something went wrong. Please try again.`.

If I try the request again using the first ID I used and succeeded with, it works.

Anyone know what I could be missing here?

If any code is needed, let me know.

Comment: Did you send both the class and object JSON objects within the JWT, or did you send the class JSON to Google separately? Can you share the JSON payloads you used (in both the case that worked and the case that failed)?